# how to use while loop in array using php?

Tags: php

How to add list of result values to array? My code is like that:

```
function report_details($display = null) {
    if($display){
        $imagePath = SITEURL . "images/";
    } else {
        $imagePath = SITEPATH . "images/";
    }   
    include("includes/db.php");
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM survey_details");

    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $sqlimg = $con->query("SELECT * FROM photo_img WHERE surv_id='$row[survey_id]'");   
        $resimg = $sqlimg->fetch_assoc();

        $reportdetails = array(
            array('BrandIcon' => $imagePath . "facebook.png",'Comapany' => "facebook",'Rank' => "2",'Link' => "http://www.facebook.com"),

            );
        return $reportdetails;  
    }

}
```

Comment: Change this `$reportdetails = ..` to this `$reportdetails[] = ...` and also use `return` outside `while loop`.

Comment: you want to save what to what?? specify

Comment: question not enough..specify more

Comment: Please go through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <?php
        function report_details($display = null) {                
            if($display){
                $imagePath = SITEURL . "images/";
            } else {
                $imagePath = SITEPATH . "images/";
            }   
            include("includes/db.php");
        $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM survey_details");

        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $sqlimg = $con->query("SELECT * FROM photo_img WHERE surv_id='$row[survey_id]'");   
        $resimg = $sqlimg->fetch_assoc();
// hoping you want to save all the details to an array
            $reportdetails[] = array( //this array saves the details each time the loop runs.
            'BrandIcon' => $imagePath . "facebook.png",
            'Comapany' => "facebook",
            'Rank' => "2",
            'Link' => "http://www.facebook.com"
            );    
        }    
    return $reportdetails;  
        }
```

Hope this works

Comment: Maybe add some explanation here

Answer (score 0):

```
function report_details($display = null) {
    if($display){
        $imagePath = SITEURL . "images/";
    } else {
        $imagePath = SITEPATH . "images/";
    }   
    include("includes/db.php");
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM survey_details");

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
$sqlimg = $con->query("SELECT * FROM photo_img WHERE surv_id='$row[survey_id]'");   
$resimg = $sqlimg->fetch_assoc();

    $reportdetails[] = array(
        array('BrandIcon' => $imagePath . "facebook.png",'Comapany' => "facebook",'Rank' => "2",'Link' => "http://www.facebook.com"),

    );

}
return $reportdetails;      
}
```